# Django rest-framework getting number of registered users in a given date range

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django, I wanted to get the number of registered users in a given date range grouped by the registration date  here is my code

```
profiles = Profile.objects.filter(date_joined__gte=datetime.date(2011, 1, 1),
                                      date_joined__lte=datetime.date(2018, 2,
                                                                     28)).annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by('date_joined')
```

I want it to return as a JSON in the form

```
{
    'date': '2018-01-01',
    'user_count': 14264
},
```

I have created a Profile Serializer but I do not think the two are compatible, the fields in Profile are not the ones I want to return

Person model

```
class Profile(User):
department = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username + " (" + self.department + " )"
```

Person Serializer

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I don't think serializer is a way to go. Serializer is meant to convert a model to some transferable-over-http format or the other way around. Whereas you want a custom report (not backed by any model). I'd just go for custom view which returns this info

Comment: Use `viewsets.ViewSet` with `list` and `retrieve` and get what you exactly need. OR you can do custom work there.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this and it worked

```
profiles = Profile.objects.filter(date_joined__gte=datetime.date(2011, 1, 1),
                                      date_joined__lte=datetime.date(2018, 2,
                                                                     28)).extra({'date': 'date(date_joined)'})\
        .values('date').annotate(count=Count('date'))

    countArray = []

    for profile in profiles:
        data = {'date_joined': str(profile['date']), 'count': profile['count']}
        countArray.append(data)

    return Response(json.dumps(countArray))
```